# prevProps and this.props will always return same value in componentDidUpdate when using react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When a user clicks Log in link in navigation, the page shows a modal. The navbar and modal is contained in `AppHeader` component.
The other component called `ActionBar` has a login button too. So I used `react-redux` to communicate between different components.
Here is my implementation. (`store.js` is omitted.)

**actionTypes.js**

```
export const LOGIN_FORM_SHOW = 'LOGIN_FORM_SHOW'
```

**actions.js**

```
import { LOGIN_FORM_SHOW } from './actionTypes'
export const loginFormShow = () => ({
   type: LOGIN_FORM_SHOW,
   payload: {}
})
```

**reducer.js**

```
import { LOGIN_FORM_SHOW } from './actionTypes'
const defaultState = { 
  loginFormVisible: false 
}
export default function(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case LOGIN_FORM_SHOW: {
      return { 
        ...state,
        loginFormVisible: true 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**AppHeader.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import LoginModal from '../components/LoginModal'
import {authService} from 'services/auth'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {loginFormShow} from "../../redux/actions"

class AppHeader extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      loginFormVisible: this.props.loginFormVisible ? true : false
    }
    this.showLoginModal = this.showLoginModal.bind(this)
  }
  showLoginModal() {
    this.setState({
      loginFormVisible: true
    })
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if(this.props.loginFormVisible) {
      this.showLoginModal()
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        // ... rest omitted
        <nav><ul>
          <li onClick={this.showLoginModal}>Login</li>
        </ul></nav>
        // ... ... ...
        <LoginModal 
          open = {this.state.loginFormVisible}
          onClose = { () => { this.setState(loginFormVisible: false) } }
        />  
      </>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    loginFormVisible: state.loginFormVisible
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, 
  null
)(AppHeader)
```

**ActionBar.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {loginFormShow} from "../../redux/actions"
import {connect} from "react-redux"

class ActionBar extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.loginFormShow}>Log In</button>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(
  null,
  { loginFormShow }
)(ActionBar)
```

Log in button in `AppHeader` works fine. But button in `ActionBar` shows a problem.

When a login modal is shown after button in `ActionBar` has been clicked. You cannot close login modal because `componentDidUpdate` method will be called and props.loginFormVisible will **always return true**.

Since `react-redux` delivers store state as props, there is no way you can modify props. So you cannot tell whether request from `ActionBar` has been actually handled and it's OK to close login modal. **`prevProps` and `props` will always be same after first button click in `ActionBar`.**

I can define another actionType LOGIN_FORM_CLOSE and fix this issue but I think there lies *some limitation* of `react-redux`.

Without using actionType LOGIN_FORM_CLOSE, my workaround is as follows:

**AppHeader.js**

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapShot) {
  if((!prevProps.lastHandled || (this.props.lastHandled - prevProps.lastHandled)) && this.props.loginFormVisible) {
    this.showLoginModal()
  }
}
// ....
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const props = { loginFormVisible: state.loginFormVisible }
  if (state.loginFormVisible) {
    props.lastHandled= (new Date).getTime()
  }
}
```

Why does `react-redux` only map store state to props?. You cannot access component's state in `mapStateToProps`. I find it hard to use.

Comment: Can't you just check if the login is visible too?   `if(this.props.loginFormVisible && !this.state.loginFormVisible) ` then it will only change state if the form isn't visible.

Comment: Closing modal will trigger componentDidUpdate and it will show modal again.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your `componentDidUpdate`.  You can conditionally render your component based on `this.props.loginFormVisible`

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        // ... rest omitted
        <nav><ul>
          <li onClick={this.showLoginModal}>Login</li>
        </ul></nav>
        // ... ... ...
        {this.props.loginFormVisible && <LoginModal 
          open = {this.state.loginFormVisible}
          onClose = { () => { this.setState(loginFormVisible: false) } }
        /> } 
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

This is a simple way to reduce interference from your `componentDidUpdate`.  You may be able to get rid of your `open` prop as well, and simplify things.

Redux is great when trying to synchronize state between components.  Because you're in a situation where you need to share state across at least 2 components, and both of those components need to be able to alter and/or read state, I would recommend keeping `loginFormVisible` in your store's state.  I would read it as a prop in both components, and only alter it through actions.  So making a `LOGIN_FORM_CLOSE` action is a great idea.  Whenever you have a line like `this.state = { loginFormVisible: this.props.loginFormVisible ? true : false }`, you need to reconsider where you want your state to live.  In your case, its probably better managed completely in the store for this piece of state.